# mysql how to select years when all three given countries participated?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns year and country.

+------+-----------------
| year |      country     
+------+-----------------
| 1957 | The Netherlands 
| 1957 | Belgium         
| 1957 | Luxembourg      
| 1954 | Hungary         
| 1954 | Belgium         
| 1932 | USA             
+------+-----------------

I am trying to list the years when Luxembourg AND The Netherlands AND Belgium participated. I should get 1957 but I don't know how to do that in mysql.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by country` and set a condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select year 
from tablename 
where country in ('Luxembourg', 'The Netherlands', 'Belgium')
group by year
having count(distinct country) = 3
```

You may remove `distinct` if there is no case of duplicate combinations of `year` and `country`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpJxq3YV26E5zxfSjEzWnD/0).
Results:

```
| year |
| ---- |
| 1957 |
```